# Why aren't auto-pilot systems used on helicopters to make them trivially easy to fly?

Tags: helicopter, autopilot

As far as my understanding of helicopters goes, it is generally much harder to learn to pilot a helicopter when compared to a plane. This is because a helicopter is naturally unstable and would crash if left on it's own, while the airplane has aerodynamic stability when up in the air.

But why aren't there auto-pilot systems for helicopters to take all the difficult work away? There are already [auto hover systems](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/27109/do-helicopters-have-an-auto-hover-system) available for helicopters, so shouldn't it be possible to manufacture a helicopter that is trivially easy to handle?

Obviously a lot more goes into piloting than just controlling the aircraft, but it would be great to be able to skip a large chunk of it.

Comment: [Related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/23977/why-not-simplified-fly-by-wire-helicopter-controls).

Comment: *This is because a helicopter is naturally unstable and would crash if left on it's own, while the airplane has aerodynamic stability when up in the air*  Nope.  A "naturally unstable" helicopter won't fly. The challenge of designing an effective helicopter is to account for that which works against stability. *But why aren't there auto-pilot systems for helicopters to take all the difficult work away?* There are, so you are assuming an answer into your question, which is an invalid form of asking a question.

Comment: A good number of people who thought that fixed wing aircraft, and rotary wing, aircraft are "trivially easy to fly" are now **dead**.

Comment: Assuming rotorcraft autopilots don't exist seems contradictory with [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/15476/3201): "*All modern offshore helicopters that I've encountered have them and they are used extensively. Usually they are engaged shortly after take-off and disengaged shortly before landing.*"

Comment: You need fly by wire not auto pilot

Comment: not true entirely about stability of aircrafts. All fighters now are statically unstable and wouldn't fly without FBW. Some are so highly unstable in certain conditions that they can diverge from stable condition within fraction of seconds.